# How to decrease ImageIcon double array execution time in Java

Tags: java, swing, file, imageicon, execution-time

I have a class that creates a double array of Files given an array of Strings that specify the name of each folder. The Files are then used to create a double array of ImageIcons, one for each image File. A JLabel with one of the ImageIcons is added to a JPanel which is added to the JFrame, but this takes roughly five seconds. How can I decrease this execution time?

```
class Test extends JFrame
{    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String [] issues = {"economic", "social", "immigration"};
        Test test = new Test(issues);
    }

    public Test (String [] issues) {
        File [][] files = getFiles(issues);
        ImageIcon [][] icons = getIconArrays(files);
        getPanel(icons);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(700, 300);
        setLocation(550, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

    public File [][] getFiles(String [] issues){
        File [][] files = new File[issues.length][];
        for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++) {
            File folder = new File("/Users/hecto/Documents/BlueJ Projects/politic/questions/" +
            issues[i] + "/");
            files[i] = folder.listFiles();
        }
        return files;
    }

    public ImageIcon [][] getIconArrays(File [][] files){
        ImageIcon [][] icons = new ImageIcon[files.length][files[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<files[i].length;j++){
                icons[i][j] = new ImageIcon(files[i][j].toString());
                icons[i][j] = new ImageIcon
                (icons[i][j].getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            }
        }
        return icons;
    }

    public void getPanel(ImageIcon [][] icons){
        JPanel picPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icons[0][0]); //initially set to first image
        picPanel.add(label);
        add(picPanel);
    }
}
```

I am sure the problem lies in the creation of the ImageIcon double array.

Comment: If you run any existing image gallery application, you’ll notice that it loads the images in the background, rather than trying to load them all in advance.  This includes the Microsoft Windows “Explorer” desktop shell.

Comment: why scale the image why not just set the image view to fit the image.

Comment: also you are loading the image into the array then overwriting it with the scaled version.

Comment: @mavriksc the images vary in size, some are very large. And yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: pre-calculate and store the thumbnail images.

Comment: @VGR what do you mean by this?

Comment: Create a directory.  Copy a lot of images into it.  Then open the directory in the desktop.  You can see the images being loaded, one by one.  The desktop does not wait for all of them to be loaded before displaying the window.

Comment: @VGR how does this apply to this program? I am already extracting images from folder directories.

Comment: @mavriksc are you suggesting I change the dimensions of the images before compiling the program?

Comment: You might get a slight speed increase by using SCALE_FAST instead of SCALE_SMOOTH.  But really, the way other programs have solved this problem is by loading images in a different thread, because there is no way to speed up the loading of images.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use SCALE_FAST instead of SCALE_SMOOTH, depending on the count of images it will give you a fair boost of the loading time.

2) use parallelization (e.g. with an ExecutorService).

There are not much more options, Image Loading takes its time (of course you could use a different image scale, format and so on, but I think that is obvious).
Load them in the background while initializing Swing (also with parallelization).

Comment: This decreases execution time by very little. I chose to resize the images instead.